# About example code from google

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Why is this done

```
uri = urlparse(self.request.uri)
if uri.query:
    query = parse_qs(uri.query)
    try:
        query = query['query'][0]
    except KeyError, err:
        query = ''
```

And not simply this

`query = self.request.get('query')`

? What will the difference be between to two code blocks?

Source. https://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/search/python/search_demo.py?r=157

Comment: Where have you seen this? Is there any context?

Comment: @Greg IT is here: https://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/search/python/search_demo.py?r=157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few differences.  The biggest is if the key `query` appears multiple times in the uri, the first version will return the first instance while the second version will return the last instance.

Also, in the second version, if the key doesn't exist you'll get `None` instead of `''`

Potentially the author of v1 just didn't trust webob to parse his query string properly.