# How to interpret a very brief intermittent exception message and trace it more if possible

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm not getting an informative trace from python, I'm just getting a message saying `InvalidRequest` for a request that is working intermittently despite that I'm investigating the trace. All I get is that python says "InvalidRequest" and when I catch the error it just says which search query failed, a search query which is working if I put it in the search box as a query. So it doesn't make sense that it is random error and not a timeout and it doesn't help me at all categorizing the error as an InvalidRequest.

What can be done?

The questions I asked which didn't solve the problem are

- [What does this error message mean in appengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459976/what-does-this-error-message-mean-in-appengine)
- [About example code from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498752/about-example-code-from-google)
- [Why "InvalidRequest" on 2nd hit of page 2 of pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499641/why-invalidrequest-on-2nd-hit-of-page-2-of-pagination)

A live view of the problem can be found if paging forward through the region-based lists on [this site](http://koolbusiness.com) and a page 2 or 3 on a subsequent reload (or at first hit) will look like getting an empty result for a timeout error but it is not a timeout. If you get to page 2 of the pagination and then press reload then it can fail or work randomly in a shorter time than a timeout would've been.

So I need help to understand what is going on. I don¨t understand what I'm doing wrong. The code looks good to me, what do you think?

```
def find_documents(query_string, limit, cursor):
    try:
        date_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='date',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().date())

        hr_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='hour',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().hour)

        min_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='minute',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().minute)

        # Sort up to  matching results by subject in descending order

        sort = search.SortOptions(expressions=[date_desc, hr_desc,
                                  min_desc], limit=ACCURACY)

        # Set query options

        options = search.QueryOptions(limit=50, cursor=cursor,
                sort_options=sort, number_found_accuracy=10000,
              #  returned_fields=['title', 'city', 'region','category', 'adID', 'date','price', 'type', 'company_ad', 'adID', 'cityID','regionID', 'hour','minute'],
             #snippeted_fields=['text']
              )
        query = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=options)
        index = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME)
        logging.debug('query_string i find %s' , str(query.query_string))
        logging.debug('query_options i find %s' , str(query.options))
        # Execute the query
        return index.search(query)

    except search.PutError as e:
        logging.exception('caught PutError %s', e)

    except search.InternalError as e:
        logging.exception('caught InternalError %s', e)

    except search.DeleteError as e:
        logging.exception('caught DeleteError %s', e)

    except search.TransientError as e:
        logging.exception('caught TransientError %s', e)

    except search.InvalidRequest as e:
        logging.exception('caught InvalidError %s', e)

    except search.Error as e:
        logging.exception('caught unknown error  %s', e)

    return None
```

Removing the ordering completely results in the same error:

```
def find_documents(query_string, limit, cursor):
    try:
        #date_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='date',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime(2013,01,01))

        #hr_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='hour',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=1)

        #min_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='minute',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=1)

        # Sort up to  matching results by subject in descending order

        #sort = search.SortOptions(expressions=[date_desc, hr_desc,
                                  min_desc], limit=ACCURACY)

        # Set query options

        options = search.QueryOptions(limit=50, cursor=cursor,
                #sort_options=sort,
                number_found_accuracy=10000,
              #  returned_fields=['title', 'city', 'region','category', 'adID', 'date','price', 'type', 'company_ad', 'adID', 'cityID','regionID', 'hour','minute'],
             #snippeted_fields=['text']
              )
        query = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=options)
        index = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME)
        logging.debug('query_string i find %s' , str(query.query_string))
        logging.debug('query_options i find %s' , str(query.options))
        # Execute the query
        return index.search(query)
```

### Solved

Comment: I repeatedly got this error on page 2 on your site. For this query: http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4694186 page 2 ALWAYS dies. Are you sure this is intermittent?

Comment: @Bert Thank you for the comment. I just tried and a could get result from 1st hit and 2nd page from the uri you mention, but on reload it did fail on first attempt to do reload.

Comment: Strange: Once you get an error, reusing that same url always fails.  The url was tool long for comment so I included it here. http://pastebin.com/9rN0nY6u .

Comment: @Bert Yes the behavior is strange. Please help me solve it and you will get the bounty. I can even ddouble the bounty since this is my only bug and I care much more for problemsolving than my rep.

Comment: Does removing the sort options stop the bug?

Comment: Oh, default values, can you set them to a fixed date in the past (not sure if swapping out new defaults causes the cursor to go screwy). Minute - default to 1, Hour - default to 1 and date default 2013-01-01.

Comment: @Bert Thanks a lot, I'll try what you mention and report back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33548/discussion-between-bert-and-909-niklas)

Comment: Your question still mentions that using historical date didn't work. Perhaps edit the question? Thanks

Comment: @RobCurtis Ok. The mentioning was there because I made the change and forgot to deploy it. When I deployed it it's working. Now my project has no bugs at all and I'm so glad for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default date to an historical value (date in the past). now() changes on the next page of data.